# What is NK-cell compartments?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, immunology

with respect to the paper:

[Adaptive reconfiguration of the human NK-cell compartment in response to cytomegalovirus: A different perspective of the host-pathogen interaction](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23552990)

What is meant by NK-cells compartment?
 I searched Google but couldn't find a proper text that would help me understand what it means.. Google search shows papers which has this term, but I need to understand what it means before reading the paper. Please help.

Comment: I agree that you need to know the basics. But I got answers to your term on googling. Here's one: [NK Cell Compartments and Their Activation by Dendritic Cells](http://www.jimmunol.org/content/172/3/1333.full). Read the first two paragraphs.

Comment: In my very brief search, it appears to refer to the expression of specific surface markers.

Comment: @anongoodnurse You can post that as an answer. This is not that obvious to be classified as homework (someone VTCed this as homework).